# unable to combine 2 arrays into a hash - ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I’m having a few problems creating a hash out of 2 arrays in ruby (1.9.2)

My issue is some of the hash keys are the same and it seems to cause an issue

So my first array (called listkey) contains these 5 items

```
puts listkey

service_monitor_errorlog
service_monitor_errorlog
wmt_errorlog
wmt_errorlog
syslog
```

the second ( called listvalue) contains these 5 items

```
puts listvalue

service_monitor_errorlog.0
service_monitor_errorlog.current
wmt_errorlog.0
wmt_errorlog.current
syslog.txt
```

what I want is a hash which contains all 5 items e.g.

```
{
"service_monitor_errorlog"=>"service_monitor_errorlog.0", 
"service_monitor_errorlog"=>"service_monitor_errorlog.current", 
"wmt_errorlog"=>"wmt_errorlog.0", 
"wmt_errorlog"=>"wmt_errorlog.current", 
"syslog"=>"syslog.txt"
}
```

However using the hash zip command

```
MyHash = Hash[listkey.zip(listvalue)]
```

I get this hash produced

```
puts MyHash
{
"service_monitor_errorlog"=>"service_monitor_errorlog.current", 
"wmt_errorlog"=>"wmt_errorlog.current", 
"syslog"=>"syslog.txt"
}
```

Can anyone help? I’ve tried all sorts of commands to merge the 2 arrays into a hash but none of them seem to work

Cheers

Mike

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

EDIT

I've just found out hashs have to have unique keys so could anyone help me work out a way to combine the arrays to form a hash with the values as arrays e.g.

```
{
"service_monitor_errorlog"=>["service_monitor_errorlog.0", "service_monitor_errorlog.current"]
"wmt_errorlog"=> ["wmt_errorlog.0", "wmt_errorlog.current"]
"syslog"=> ["syslog.txt"]
}
```

Comment: You can't have two exact same keys in hash

Comment: site note: use "p" or "pp" or "puts obj.inspect" to inspect objects, "puts" makes a mess of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.9 I'd probably do this:

```
  listkey.zip(listvalue).each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |(k,v), h| 
    h[k] << v
  end
```

Example:

```
a=['a','b','c','a']
b=[1,2,3,4]
a.zip(b).each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |(k,v), h| h[k] << v } 
#=> {"a"=>[1, 4], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your updated question, an (ugly) solution is

```
the_hash = listkey.zip(listvalue).inject({}) do | a, (k, v) | 
  a[k] ||= []
  a[k] << v
  a
end
```

or (without the `inject`)

```
the_hash = {}
listkey.zip(listvalue).each do | k, v | 
  the_hash[k] ||= []
  the_hash[k] << v
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering the answer after the edit. `group_by` is a bit inconvenient in this case, so let's use facets' `map_by`, which is a group_by that allows you to decide what you want to accumulate:

```
require 'facets'
Hash[xs.zip(ys).map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }]
#=> {"syslog"=>["syslog.txt"],
#    "service_monitor_errorlog"=>
#      ["service_monitor_errorlog.0", "service_monitor_errorlog.current"],
#    "wmt_errorlog"=>["wmt_errorlog.0", "wmt_errorlog.current"]}
```

Comment: Thanks all I'll give these a go and let you know how it works out

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
a=['a','b','c','a']
b=[1,2,3,4]

c=Hash.new

a.each_with_index do |value,key|
  #puts key
  #puts value
  c[value]=b[key]
end
puts c
```

Output is

```
{"a"=>4, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

This means **key should be unique**